# Big O running time for this algorithm[function call from within a loop]?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, runtime-analysis

So the basic doubt i had started with this piece of code

```
def fn2(a,n):
    .
    .
    for i in range(0,n):
        .
        .
        .

def fn1():
    .
    .
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        fn2(a,i)
```

Would this be considered as a loop within a loop or will this take more than the usual O(n<sup>2</sup>) or would it take greater time then that ?

Comment: If $fn1$ and $fn2$ do nothing depending on $n$ besides the for-loops, then it is $O(n^2)$.

Comment: Imagine that you substitute the code of fn2 inside the code of fn1. Does this make the situation any clearer?

Comment: no for clarity i just wrote about one loop in the example , actually fn2 is a function having multiple loops and memory allocations used as a subroutine within fn1 .

Comment: You don't "consider as a loop within a loop". You count the operations. How many operations are there?